# How to use regex to select a character outside of and after a set of quotations

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm looking for a regex expression to handle select the comment in VB code, but not select the a single quote inside of string. And not select the EoL(\r\n)

I can get a regex to select the first 2 situations, ts the 3rd that i am struggling with.

```
   'select this text to end of line
Dim x As String = "do not select this text" 'select this here to end of line    
Dim x As String = "do not select ' this text" 'select this here to end of line
```

Been trying many variations of Lookaheads and such.
Just can't get it right.
Seen a few other answers on stacko, that have not worked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'(?![^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/7

This will not select a `'` which in between `""`

Comment: This worked, Thanks. Going to us this one. Not which is better the simple below or the more comprehensive one above. I figure his one may handle some situation i'm not thinking of.

Comment: @YogurtTheWise yes this will handle most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex.

```
'[^"]*$
```

OR

```
'['"]*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bO4zV5/1)